# MSBuild props file does not get evaluated when imported by a nuget package, but works when manually imported

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I have created a number of nuget packages with msbuild targets that help me take care of common boilerplate in my .NET projects. Here I am working on a simple `.props` file which is aimed to make the copyright information in the compiled assembly and the nuget package consistent.

Currently I am struggling with the fact that this props file does not get respected in all build phases of a target project.

The props file looks roughly like the following (full source code available in [github](https://github.com/vdimensions/vdimensions_msbuild_sdk/blob/master/src/Copyright/VDimensions.MSBuild.Sdk.Copyright.props)):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyrightYearCurrent Condition=" '$(CopyrightYearCurrent)' == '' ">$([System.DateTime]::get_UtcNow().get_Year())</CopyrightYearCurrent>
  <CopyrightYear>$(CopyrightYearCurrent)</CopyrightYear>
  <!-- CopyrightYearSince may be defined externally in the consuming project and is non-mandatory -->
  <CopyrightYear Condition=" '$(Authors)' != '' AND '$(CopyrightYearSince)' != '' ">$(CopyrightYearSince)-$(CopyrightYearCurrent)</CopyrightYear>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <Copyright Condition=" '$(Authors)' != '' AND '$(Copyright)' == '' ">Copyright © $(Authors) $(CopyrightYear)</Copyright>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyCompany Condition=" '$(AssemblyCompany)' == '' AND '$(Authors)' != '' ">$(Authors)</AssemblyCompany>
  <AssemblyCopyright Condition=" '$(AssemblyCopyright)' == '' AND '$(Copyright)' != '' ">$(Copyright)</AssemblyCopyright>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In a target project, I have a `DirectoryBuild.props` placed in my root directory, where I need to activate the props file.

My goal is, when I run `dotnet build`, or `dotnet pack` from the command line, the Copyright-related information from msbuild to propagate both to the assembly attributes, and to the nuget package.

Initially, during the development of the props, I just imported the props file using the MSBuild `Import` directive into my `DirectoryBuild.props`, and all was working as expected.

Because the props looked quite generic I decided to create a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VDimensions.MSBuild.Sdk.Copyright) out of it so I can reuse it in more than a single project, and maintain it from a central place. Then I replaced the `Import` of the props file inside of `DirectoryBuild` with a `PackageReference` directive.

Now, when I execute `dotnet pack`, the produced nuget package (and the respective nuspec file which is auto-generated in the obj folder) no longer contain the `copyright` field. At the same time, the compiled dll files have their copyright information correctly applied.

I have examined the complete msbuild output for both scenarios (using the command `dotnet build -pp:msbuild.xml`) and there are no significant difference in the import order of the props file from the package vs the manually imported file from `Directory.Build.props`, and so I am stuck with understanding the observed behaviour.

Here is the output of `dotnet --info` if it is of any use to someone:

> .NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
> Version:   5.0.202
> Commit:    db7cc87d51
>
> Runtime Environment:
> OS Name:     Windows
> OS Version:  10.0.19042
> OS Platform: Windows
> RID:         win10-x64
> Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\
>
> Host (useful for support):
> Version: 5.0.5
> Commit:  2f740adc14

**Update**

Just to weed out any suspicions, the nuget package is properly built (the name of the package and the targets it imports are the same) and my IDE (JetBrains Rider) correctly detects that the `.props` file from the nuget package is loaded.

Also, `CopyrightYearSince` and `Authors` are defined in my `Directory.Build.props` before the `PackageReference` directive.

**Update 2**

It seems the issue occurs only when generating the automatically produced nuspec file. Every override in a props file of a property that should take part in the nuspec is ignored, however, it is used appropriately in the other build tasks. The problem disapears if the props file is directly referred to, as opposed to being used from a nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is more complex, because it happens when cross-targeting projects are involved.

Thanks to [a github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/4747) I got more insight on how the `GenerateNuspec` task is working with imported msbuild tasks, props and targets, so I came to a solution for my own problem. The details below:

The use-case where the problematic behavior is observed is because:

1. My nuget packages containing props and targets only include them under `build`, but not under the `buildCrossTargeting` folders.
2. The linked above issue showed me, that when the project is cross-targeting, the `GenerateNuspec` flow will only include custom props/targets present in the `buildCrossTargeting` folder, thus my targets got ignored
3. When I produced a new nuget package where I used both `build` and `buildCrossTargeting`, the issue disappeared.

Conclusion -- be very careful when creating your own msbuild targets as nuget packages -- scenarios such as cross-targeting projects need special handling!